# Disable Netbeans automatic svn ignore?

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans6.7

How do I stop Netbeans from automatically `svn ignore`-ing "`.swp`" files?

I use Netbeans as my main development environment, but I often use gvim at the same time for quick edits.  gvim creates temporary files with the .swp extension, and Netbeans seems to be scanning my code folders and adding an `svn ignore` property for these files.

I can see how this would be useful to people, but I want to disable it - the .swp files don't show up as being unversioned anyway, so they're not a problem, but the directory modifications caused by the `svn ignore`'s just creates a load of modification spam when I'm using the svn command line interface.

Any idea how I can disable this feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [here](http://www.mojavelinux.com/wiki/doku.php?id=java:javacheatsheet):

> Get NetBeans to stop adding VIM swap files to .cvsignore or svn:ignore
>
> - Open $HOME/.netbeans/6.1/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/core.properties
> - Remove everything in the IgnoredFiles property after the last pipe character (|) (i.e., |^\..*$) and append ^.svn$
> - Restart NetBeans
>
> You can also find this setting under the Files tab in the Options

---

As mentioned by [therefromhere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8331/therefromhere) in the comments:

- In netbeans 6.7 this is in `Tools->Options->Miscellaneous->Files`
- the relevant pattern to append in this case was **`^.*\.swp$`**

Comment: Excellent!  Note that in netbeans 6.7 this in Tools->Options->Miscellaneous->Files , and the relevant pattern to append in my case was ^*.swp$

Comment: Trying to recreate this on another system, I think must have made a mistake in that comment. I think the regex should be ^.*.swp$

Comment: Let's try that one more time.  `^.*\.swp$` works.  (ie any string ending with the literal string `".swp"` )