# How can I show .git folder in Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, directory, netbeans-7

I have a project which I check out remotely from my VM.

Now it checks out all files except the one that he doesn't see.

Which happens to be the `.git` folder...

I already removed the regex from the

```
options->miscellenous->files
```

From

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!htaccess$).*$
```

to

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!htaccess$)$
```

But the folder itself still doesn't get pulled...

Anyone has a solution for this?

I am using Netbeans 7.3 64 bit on windows 7.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your solution should work, as illustrated in the comments of "[Display hidden dot files and directories in NetBeans](http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2008/06/display-hidden-dot-files-and.html)":

> In Netbeans 7.1 it's also in `Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files`

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!htaccess$).*$
```

> Just the remove the `.*` at the end and you're fine.

But all the references I have seen (like my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074430/6309)) mention that you need to restart NetBeans to see that updated pattern takes effect.
Or at least try a `Source->Scan for External Changes`, as mentioned in "[How do I refresh Netbeans workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9107475/6309)".

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Netbeans 8.2, any update on this?

Comment: @oidualc Try asking a new question with screenshot illustrating the issue.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39973365/how-can-i-show-git-folder-in-netbeans-8-2) it is

Answer (score 0):

You can make visible only .git file. like this

go in Netbeans 8 in Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files

and enter

> ^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^.(?!(htaccess|git.+|hgignore)$).*$