# NetBeans fails to recognize and/or create folders that start with '.'?

Tags: netbeans, ide, directory, naming

At least in Windows, folders with names starting with '.' (dot) characters are valid, and it's possible to create or name folders starting with a '.' (dot) character by ending the folder's name with a '.' (dot) during creation or rename.

NetBeans (8.0.2 and DEV) seems to fail to recognize such folders, making them unavailable or invisible in the "Projects" or "Files" tabs.

During the creation of such named folders, NetBeans further fails to close the "New Folder" window, after clicking "Finish", although, in the real file-system, the file gets created successfully.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I suspect this may be more of a Windows thing. A few apps have trouble with folders/files that start with a period as that is used for file extensions. In *nix environments, anything starting with a period is hidden by default in a directory listing.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15705406/4050842

Comment: @Thaillie This solves the issue with invisible folders (I'll add to the answer), but the folder-creation bug persists.

Comment: @TheLima, This was to show that that part of the "bug" is intended behavior. And it was to show what `Jiri Prox` meant in his comment on the bug tracker

Comment: @Thaillie Understood. Although it may still be a bug in that, it may be that only `Files` are supposed to be ignored, not `Folders`. I simply don't know; and it will hopefully be clarified by NB staff or major contributors on the bugtracker. But thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders starting with `.` are ignored by NetBeans by default. To change this behavior, go to `Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files` and remove `.*` from the end of the *Ignored Files Pattern*, thus changing it from:
`^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|git.+|hgignore)$).*$`
to...
`^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|git.+|hgignore)$)$`

---

As for the folder-creation problem, yes, this is a bug with the NetBeans IDE.

[I submitted the issue (#256500) to the NetBean's bugtracker.](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=256500)